# Bash custom function to change directory

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash function to change my directory to a folder only passing a specific code

```
change() {
   cd "~/Documents/user/projects_folder/$1"
}
```

However this is giving me an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't put the `~` inside quotes.

Comment: `change() { cd ~/"Documents/user/projects_folder/$1"; }` will work fine -- the only change being moving the quotes to start only after the tilde. Or of course you can use `$HOME` inside quotes without any problem.